# Perl Regex Error Help

Tags: perl, utf-8, substitution

I'm receiving a similar error in two completely unrelated places in our code that we can't seem to figure out how to resolve. The first error occurs when we try to parse XML using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm):

```
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected end of string) in substitution (s///) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/XML/LibXML/Error.pm line 217.
```

And the second is when we try to do simple string substitution:

```
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x78, immediately after start byte 0xe9) in substitution (s///) at /gold/content/var/www/alltrails.com/cgi-bin/API/Log.pm line 365.
```

The line in question in our Log.pm file is as follows where `$message` is a string:

```
$message =~ s/\s+$//g;
```

Our biggest problem in troubleshoot this is that we haven't found a way to identify the input that is causing this to occur. My hope is that some else has run into this issue before and can provide advice or sample code that will help us resolve it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've had a lot of suggestions to capture the input which I do appreciate, but can any one actually help with resolving the problem?

Comment: We're surmising your XML is broken. When you find out in which way it is broken, then it becomes clear how to fix it, and consequently the error will not occur anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the cause is, but if you want to log the message that is causing this, you could always add a `__DIE__` signal handler to make sure you capture the error:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { 
  if ($_[0] =~ /Malformed UTF-8 character/) { 
    print STDERR "message = $message\n"; 
  } 
};
```

That should at least let you know what string is triggering these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a hex dump of the source data to see what it looks like?

If your reading this from a file, you can do this with a tool like "od".

Or, you can do this inside the perl script itself by passing the string to a function like this:

```
sub DumpString {
    my @a = unpack('C*',$_[0]);
    my $o = 0;
    while (@a) {
        my @b = splice @a,0,16;
        my @d = map sprintf("%03d",$_), @b;
        my @x = map sprintf("%02x",$_), @b;
        my $c = substr($_[0],$o,16);
        $c =~ s/[[:^print:]]/ /g;
        printf "%6d %s\n",$o,join(' ',@d);
        print " "x8,join('  ',@x),"\n";
        print " "x9,join('   ',split(//,$c)),"\n";
        $o += 16;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an "XML" file that is expected to have UTF-8 encoded characters but doesn't.  Try just opening it and looking for hibit characters.

Comment: if that is the case is there some way to update the way we pass the data to XML::Simple the handle different encoding methods. For the other issue, is there some way to automatically convert the current string to UTF-8 format so this isn't an issue moving forward?

Comment: @Russell C.: first figure out what the problem is and if it is in the file or in your handling of the file before it gets to XML::Simple